# Sorting HealthKit data by date

Tags: swift, sorting, date, healthkit

I'm trying to get pulse data from HealthKit and sort them by date for use in a line chart. I'm running a 'for loop' to get the correct dates and put the results in an array before putting the results in the chart but it seems like they get put in a random order and I don't understand why.

```
class Pulse {
    var pulse = 0.0
    var startDate = Date()
}
```

```
var pulseData: [Pulse] = []
```

```
func getHeartBeatsForAWeek() {

        for i in 1...7 {
            getHeartBeats(startDate: date.getStartOfSpecificDateByAddingToToday(day: -i), endDate: date.getStartOfSpecificDateByAddingToToday(day: -i + 1))
        }
    }

    func getHeartBeats(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
        PulseHelper.shared.averageHearthRate(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate) { (data) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.pulseData.append(data)
                self.updateGraph()
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my function for fetching the heart rate:

```
func averageHearthRate(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, completion: @escaping (Pulse) -> Void) {

        let typeHeart = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)
        let startDate = startDate
        let endDate = endDate
        let predicate: NSPredicate? = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: HKQueryOptions.strictEndDate)

        let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: typeHeart!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .discreteAverage, completionHandler: {(query: HKStatisticsQuery, result: HKStatistics?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                let quantity: HKQuantity? = result?.averageQuantity()
                let beats: Double? = quantity?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute()))
                print("Got: \(String(format: "%.f", beats!)) from \(startDate)")

                let pulse = Pulse.init()
                pulse.pulse = beats!
                pulse.startDate = startDate
                completion(pulse)
            })
        })
        PermissionsHelper.shared.store.execute(query)
    }
```

This is what I get when I print the results:

Got: 82 from 2019-03-30 23:00:00 +0000

Got: 74 from 2019-03-31 22:00:00 +0000

Got: 73 from 2019-03-25 23:00:00 +0000

Got: 74 from 2019-03-27 23:00:00 +0000

Got: 70 from 2019-03-26 23:00:00 +0000

Got: 74 from 2019-03-29 23:00:00 +0000

Got: 108 from 2019-03-28 23:00:00 +0000

I'd like them to get in correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after adding an element to your array, you need to use the sort() function.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688499-sort) you can find the documentation about all the ways you can implement it.

In this situation, if pulseData is an array of Date ( [Date] ), you just need to call:

```
   self.pulseData.sort()
```

***EDIT:***

As you could see in the link to documentation I posted, there are several ways to use the sort() function in order to apply your sorting rule to a custom object.

In this situation, let's assume you have this class:

```
      class Pulse {
        var pulse: Double = 0.0
        var startDate = Date()

        init(p: Double,d: Date) {
        self.pulse = p
        self.startDate = d
            }
        }
```

**Create an array of Pulse objects:**

```
        let pulse1 = Pulse(p: .., d: Date(...))
        let pulse2 = Pulse(p: .., d: Date(...))
        var pulseData: [Pulse] = [pulse1, pulse2]
```

***You can sort the array in this way:***

```
        //Ascending order
        pulseData.sort(by: {$0.startDate < $1.startDate})
```

Comment: pulseData is an array of Double. I realize now that it is maybe a bad way since I want to sort by Date. I also tried with pulseData: [Double : Date] and sort the by values and add the Keyes to a new array but that didn’t work either. Maybe I did it wrong? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my own question that works. I will leave this question open because I'm pretty new to Swift and I think there are probably better ways to do this than the way I did.

```
func getHeartBeats(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
        PulseHelper.shared.averageHearthRate(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate) { (data) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.pulseData.append(data)
                self.pulseData = self.pulseData.sorted(by: {$0.startDate < $1.startDate})
                self.updateGraph()
            }
        }
    }
```

So what I did was instead of having an array of Doubles with the heart rate I created a Pulse class with pulse and startDate and sorted them by date using

```
self.pulseData.sorted(by: {$0.startDate < $1.startDate})
```

Comment: Check my answer, you can use the sort function instead of sorted.
Pretty same effect, but you don't need to do self.pulseData = self.pulseData.sorted(...)